# Web browser command line program

Tags: java, http

I am working on a web server (done), and thought I would make my own little text-based browser, the only problem is that I can't actually get the browser to read the responses. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class client
{
    static Socket socket = null;
    static BufferedReader in = null;
    static PrintWriter out = null;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int fromServer;
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 8001);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
            out.println("GET /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html.en HTTP/1.0");
            out.flush();
            while ((fromServer = in.read()) != -1)
            {
                System.out.write(fromServer);
                System.out.flush();
            }

        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unknown host");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IO error");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't completely finished the request. You need *two* newlines, as otherwise it just looks like you're still writing out the request headers.

Add an extra `println` and you *may* be okay, although as HTTP specifies CRLF for the line ending, I would actually use `print` rather than `println`, and put `\r\n` at the end of each line explicitly.

(I'd also avoid using `PrintWriter`, personally - swallowing exceptions is bad...)

Comment: What would you recommend using instead of PrintWriter?